# Jenkins Docker Slave Node failed to call checkout in a pipeline

Tags: git, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

All,
I have a Jenkins server and a docker slave node. Now the server can connect with the node and begin to run the pipeline (Jenkinsfile)

My project is a bit special, the building relies on some code from other project. So, in the pipeline I added a checkout phase as below:

```
  **checkout([
    $class: 'GitSCM', 
    branches: [[name: '*/master']], 
    gitTool: 'Default',
    userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'https://github.com/aaaaaa/bbbbbb.git'],[credentialsId: "${GITHUB_USER_CRED_ID}"]]
  ])**
```

Git is absolutely installed in the docker, I also set the tool location for this docker node. But the pipeline failed in this step and report:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hudson.Util.getDigestOf(Util.java:635)
    at jenkins.plugins.git.AbstractGitSCMSource.getCacheEntry(AbstractGitSCMSource.java:1391)
    at jenkins.plugins.git.GitToolChooser.decideAndUseCache(GitToolChooser.java:77)
    at jenkins.plugins.git.GitToolChooser.<init>(GitToolChooser.java:58)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.createClient(GitSCM.java:850)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.createClient(GitSCM.java:833)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1240)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:125)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:93)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:80)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE.
```

What's the problem? Anyone have seen this problem and know how to solve it? Thank you very very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is related to a performance related feature introduced in a recent version of the Git plugin. I replicated using v4.4.1. Changing checkout syntax to define one userRemoteConfig instead of two resolves this (more details: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-61608). If the latter does not resolve this for you, downgrade the plugin, or check "Disable performance enhancements" in the "Git plugin" section of "Configure system". More info on the new feature this setting controls here: https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/